# Deploy a solution with HTML5/Javascript project and separate ASP.NET Web API project on IIS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a website with AngularJS client part an a ASP.NET Web API backend. The website is separated in two "projects", a regular Visual Studio project for the backend, and, with no HTML projects template in Visual Studio, another ASP.NET project for the HTML part. This part is managed and build with Grunt to a dist/ subfolder.

I would like to deploy this website on Amazon EC2, in a Windows Server 2012 with IIS. I however haven't found how to package the app, modify the solution or configure IIS to make that work. Ideally, IIS should serve the static files with any request except requests on http://website/api, which should be redirected to the Web API backend.

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If AWS supports WebDeploy, you could use the Publish feature, then create a new WebDeploy package for the web application project. If AWS supports WebDeploy, you could then use this created package to publish to AWS.